# Object Cell/Range doesn't support .Font property in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to colour code cells to give the user a warning about which cell's data is incorrect before running a calculation. Currently throwing a:

> run time error 438 object doesn't support property

when trying to run through all the data.

Basically creating a worksheet to allow the user to input some data on a consist, then based off some back end data/restrictions, spit out an answer of what they can/can't do. I've got a level of error checking already in the initial code as the user inputs data (basically to try and encourage them to make sure the data they're inputting is valid before they try and run the calculation) and this works fine using a Worksheet_Change subroutine which can loop through all cells one at a time (within the target range) no worries.

If I try replicate this (using a named range instead of the Target cells from the change function) it seems to do one of two things: it will try and send through a range of cells, rather than individual cells and fail when it tries to match data from the "cells" rather than the single cell it should be trying to match, OR it will throw the 438 error when it tries to colour it in.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ErrorWagonPack As Boolean, ErrorCellsNotEmpty As Boolean, WagonPack As Integer, cel As Range, Target As Range

    ErrorWagonPack = False
    ErrorCellsNotEmpty = False
    Set Target = Application.Range("ConsistInput")

    For Each cel In Target 'issue is here somewhere I think. It's related to how the cel is created and as such what properties it can have
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        WagonPack = 0
        If Len(cel.Value) > 0 Then
            WagonPack = Application.Index(Application.Range("WagonData"), Application.Match(cel.Value, Application.Range("WagonData").Columns(1), 0), 4)
            If cel.Offset(0, 1).Value Mod WagonPack > 0 Then
                ErrorWagonPack = True
                cel.Font.ColourIndex = RGB(156, 0, 6) '438 error here
                cel.Interior.ColourIndex = RGB(255, 199, 206) '438 error here too
            End If
        End If
    Next cel

If ErrorWagonPack = True Or ErrorCellsNotEmpty = True Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'calculate stuff
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Ideally I'd like to get to a point where I run the code, colour the cells causing issues/with incorrect data, then if doesn't throw any error variables, run the calculation but the 438 error seems to be the sticking point. I'm almost willing to bet it's something simple I'm just missing but can't figure it out. Probably doesn't help I'm still pretty green with VBA.

Comment: It’s actually the American spelling of color.

Comment: sorry, im Australian... its habit

Comment: I missed that you’re using the wrong property too.

Comment: LOL, I see you did the same thing.. why cant language be universal!?

Comment: Yeah...I got caught with that too. Knew it would be something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.ColorIndex` is incorrect. Use `.Color`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ErrorWagonPack As Boolean, ErrorCellsNotEmpty As Boolean, WagonPack As Integer, cel As Range, Target As Range

    ErrorWagonPack = False
    ErrorCellsNotEmpty = False
    Set Target = Application.Range("ConsistInput")

    For Each cel In Target 'issue is here somewhere I think. It's related to how the cel is created and as such what properties it can have
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        WagonPack = 0
        If Len(cel.Value) > 0 Then
            WagonPack = Application.Index(Application.Range("WagonData"), Application.Match(cel.Value, Application.Range("WagonData").Columns(1), 0), 4)
            If cel.Offset(0, 1).Value Mod WagonPack > 0 Then
                ErrorWagonPack = True
                cel.Font.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6) '438 error here
                cel.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) '438 error here too
            End If
        End If
    Next cel

If ErrorWagonPack = True Or ErrorCellsNotEmpty = True Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'calculate stuff
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I should add `.ColorIndex` is a value between `1` and `56`. It represnts some colors but not all (obviously) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.ColorIndex

Comment: .Color works perfectly with the full RGB. ColorIndex with the correct numbers also works. Much appreciated. Knew it would be something simple. Also helps when you use the american spelling of color (force of habit)

Answer (score 1):

The `.ColorIndex` property is between 1 and 56:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    cel.Font.ColorIndex = 20

End Sub
```

The 2 RGB values go way further than 56:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print RGB(156, 0, 6)          '393372
    Debug.Print RGB(255, 199, 206)      '13551615

End Sub
```

Thus, the only values to be safely used are the 56 red values, between:

`cel.Font.ColorIndex = RGB(56, 0, 0)`

and

`cel.Font.ColorIndex = RGB(1, 0, 0)`

As an alternative, without using `ColorIndex` the `Range().Font.Color` supports the complete RGB values:

```
Range("A1").Font.Color = RGB(100, 20, 255)
```